# Pinterest Authentication with iOS-PDK

Tags: pinterest

I have been struggling with the simple task of authenticating with the ios-pdk. This has worked for me in the past but it is not consistent. I have followed all the instructions I can find: set up a re-direct uri and I am using the the latest XCode 7 with Swift 2. I am concerned it may be related to my latest upgrade. My call looks like this:

```
let permission = [PDKClientReadPublicPermissions]
PDKClient.sharedInstance().authenticateWithPermissions(permission,
                withSuccess: { (responseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in
                    print("success PDKResponseObject: \(responseObject)")

                }) { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
                    print("error NSError: \(err)")

}
```

Over the past few days, sometimes I receive a success and other days I receive an internal server error! Has anyone seen this behavior?

> Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token=[access_token_here]&fields=counts%28pins%2Clikes%2Cboards%29%2Cid%2Cbio%2Clast_name%2Ccreated_at%2Cusername%2Cimage%2Cfirst_name } { status code: 500

Thanks, Anita

Comment: Update: If I do a Product -> Clean in XCode, my error goes away and I am successfully authenticated. But... if I try to authenticate on another device using another Pinterest account. I fail with "Request failed: unauthorized (401)"

Comment: Another Update: OK, clean does not always fix the problem. It is breaking again this morning with the internal server error 500. In taking a closer look when it fails, the PDKClient.sharedInstance().authenticateWithPermissions call tries to retrieve fields and fails: fields=counts%28pins%2Clikes%2Cboards%29%2Cid%2Cbio%2Clast_name%2Ccreated_at%2Cusername%2Cimage%2Cfirst_name

Answer (score 1):

i think this may have been fixed with this pull request: https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk/commit/4386ef09ee988de1f73511552fb3e35d721962b6

Comment: I saw that also. I did an update and clean but it did not make a difference with the "Request failed: unathorized (401)" error I receive when I try to authorize a user (other than myself)

Comment: OK.. my version of PDKClient did not have the new fix. Changing that gets rid of my 500 error. I am still left with the unauthorized 401 error for authenticating users other than myself. Is there a restriction on who can be authenticated if my app has not been reviewed yet by Pinterest?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that unauthorized error I was receiving was due to the fact that the account I was testing with was not listed as a collaborator for my app.